# Airflow Error: ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I triggered a DAG , after running for sometime it showed upstream_failed. I checked task log it is showing ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8. I am not getting how to resolve it. I am running this using airflow UI.

this is the error ->

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, 
 in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 258, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 281, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 919, in log
    root=root, wrapped=conf.getboolean('webserver', 'default_wrap'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 386, in render
    return super(AirflowViewMixin, self).render(template, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 308, in render
    return render_template(template, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/ti_log.html", line 20, in top-level template code
    {% extends "airflow/task_instance.html" %}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1005, in render
    return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/ti_log.html", line 16, in root
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/task_instance.html", line 16, in root
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dag.html", line 19, in root
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/master.html", line 16, in root
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html", line 16, in root
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/base.html", line 26, in root
    <style>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html", line 90, in block_page_body
    function convertSecsToHumanReadable(seconds) {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/ti_log.html", line 34, in block_body
    <li class="active" style="float: right">
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 262, in call
    return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 93, in __call__
    return original_call(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 340, in __call__
    rv = concat(self._stack[self._depth](self._context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/task_instance.html", line 48, in block_body
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 262, in call
    return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 155, in __call__
    return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/meta.py", line 56, in render_field
    return field.widget(field, **render_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/form/widgets.py", line 63, in __call__
    return super(DateTimePickerWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 181, in __call__
    kwargs['value'] = field._value()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 736, in _value
    return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/mixins/default.py", line 124, in strftime
    return self.format(fmt, _locale.getlocale()[0], 'classic')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 587, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you try with utf8? Just a guess.

Comment: What OS are you running airflow on. The scheduler, not which os you're accessing the front-end from.

Comment: I believe you need to set some environment variable for the locale https://coderwall.com/p/-k_93g/mac-os-x-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-in-python